# Why doesn't the command upgrade work

Tags: command-line

When doing:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**E: Invalid operation upgrate**

```
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**E: Invalid operation upgrade**

Comment: @Luis the edit sort of removes the whole reason for this post.

Comment: @muru Really? If that is true then the question will be closed for the user did not even take the time to see he was typing it wrong.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado He couldn't have gotten it wrong twice in a row. I honestly think he thought that was the correct spelling.

Comment: @muru I would guess because of the way it is pronounced but still, 99.99% of all sites that show that will show how to type it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are looking for is:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

this will upgrade all the packages installed in your system to the newest version.

Don't try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` unless you know what you are doing as it can install or remove packages while upgrading.

-- Edit bz --

To upgrade you first run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This updates the list of available packages.

You then run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For additional information see the man page

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Answer (score 0):

It's `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
You can use [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8) next time to make sure what the names are.

Comment: No need for the "try searching by yourself first" comment - that comes off as harsh to new users.

Comment: Changed it, you are correct I shouldn't have done that, but it seemed so obvious he never looked.

Comment: still not a reason to be harsh at new users like that.

Comment: Upvoted. I see nothing wrong with encouraging users, new or otherwise, to use man pages. Teach a man to fish ...

Comment: It wasn't about the man pages, I edited my previous answer to sound less harsh and included the man reference.